# Продвижение сайта на Java

Tags: php, java, seo

Надеюсь, вопрос не вызовет сильного холивара. Насколько сложнее и сложнее ли осуществлять SEO продвижение сайта, написанного с использованием Sevlet/JSP, по сравнению с сайтом на PHP? С SEO лично дела не имею, но заказы на несколько сайтов имеются, и стоит вопрос выбора языка.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы выбираете язык для написания серверной части в зависимости от того, где лучше осуществляется SEO? Это очень странный выбор. Обычно языки выбирают по другим более важным критериям.

Поисковым движкам абсолютно всё равно на Java или чём-то ещё. Их интересует конкретно выходные HTML файлы.